# Problem with adding gpg while installing Tor browser: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, tor-install

I've been following instructions from the torproject.org to install Tor on Ubuntu Focal Fossa.
While running the following code:

`wget -qO- https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null`

I got the following error:
`tee: /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg: Permission denied`

Before implementing blindly from the Internet, I decided to ask for support here. Perhaps, someone has already came across such an issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this with root privileges. Add `sudo` before the `tee` command. For example:

```
wget -qO- https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

From https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/

> **Note:** The symbol # refers to running the code as root. This means you should have access to a user account with system administration privileges, e.g your user should be in the sudo group.

Comment: Thank you very much, Steve!