# Change instructions or add alternative for adding gpg key

Tags: bridge, tor-install

I have been trying to reinstall a tor bridge relay.

When following the instructions on the following page

```
https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/
```

in the section starting "3. Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following command at your command prompt:"

the very long command given did not work on my system.

When I searched for help, I found the page below

[Problem with adding gpg while installing Tor browser: Permission denied](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/23212/problem-with-adding-gpg-while-installing-tor-browser-permission-denied)

The advice, to insert sudo before the word tee in the long command, allowed the command to work.

I am writing to ask if the instructions should either just add the sudo before the work tee, if that is always required, or provide a note saying that it may be required.

My apologies if this change is already in hand.

Comment: The issue https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/web/support/-/issues/310

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better if you bring this up with the Tor Project people who manage the website. You can make a new issue at https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/web/support to explain how the instructions are unclear.

> The advice, to insert sudo before the word tee in the long command, allowed the command to work.
>
> I am writing to ask if the instructions should either just add the sudo before the work tee, if that is always required, or provide a note saying that it may be required.

The "sudo" command is only needed if you're not running in a root shell, and the guide implies that you should be running a root shell by using the "#" shell syntax.

But I agree that this is confusing when you're not already familiar with installing tor, so hopefully it can be improved if you let them know about it.